# Maintain login session web service in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, session, soap, authentication

I have to maintain user log-in that is authenticated by webservice (SOAP WSDL) in PHP, it returns id_session if logging successfully, there will be function to return error if the given id_session expired.

1. When Logging in with the user credential, I use ajax in a specific php file to verify it, so the result will be receiving from ajax response (JS), how would I use it to maintain the session in php?
2. if I use cookie to maintain it only, is it enough? is there a way to store the session id encrypted securely but still can use it?

The only idea I have is storing it in cookie, & remove the cookie's value when it's expired which does not seem to be good practice.

Comment: Your question is too broad and you don't seem to understand what a session is.  I suggest you read the [PHP manual section on sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php) to get started.

Answer (score 0):

First of all never store a plain password in a session. Also you should check the session everytime the user does something (refresh page, do a query, ...)

Also sessions aren't available in JS. You are probably thinking about cookies. And those aren't secure cause they can be tampered with if wanted to.